# How to perform Sentiment Analysis on Noun Phrases in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I need your help as i tried every method but not able to perform sentiment analysis on my noun phrases, extracted from tweets in dataframe, using TextBlob. Also i think TextBlob.noun_phrases function is not producing the correct results. See for yourself in the image below. I am really new to Python, please help!!

So my code for extracting the Noun phrase from dataframe is:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('punkt')

def blob(text):
  return TextBlob(text).noun_phrases

df['Noun_Phrases'] = df['Tweets'].apply(blob)

df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkIBu.png)

Next, my code for sentiment analysis is below, and i get the error as shown in below image:

```
def getsubjectivity(text):
return TextBlob(text).sentiment.subjectivity 

df['Subjectivity'] = df['Noun_Phrases'].apply(getsubjectivity)
```

Error : TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYWZO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about your objective. in your `getsubjectivity` function the input need to be string, seems like you are feeding it a list.

if you make the below change, you will overcome the error.

```
def getsubjectivity(text):
    text=''.join(text)
    return TextBlob(text).sentiment.subjectivity
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Basically my objective is to extract noun phrases from the tweets and get the polarity and subjectivity on noun phrases. I have to ask you one more question, if you can help. I was actually trying to perform stemming on my tweets, so i want to know it is mandatory to do tokenizing before stemming? Because if i do tokenizing then it becomes a list of words and not a string. And when it become a list of words then i am not able to perform the WordCloud on the list. For WordCloud it must be a string i guess?